# PiNoir Camera - using rolling shutter

Tags: camera, raspicam

As far as I know, the camera chip in PiNoir camera has a rolling shutter. This basically means that the camera records the image line by line, waits for all the lines, and returns them as a single image.

Is it possible to extract the lines as soon as they are recorded, instead of waiting for the whole image?

Comment: Perhaps ask at the raspberrypi.org/forums.  I think the people who know are more likely to see a post there.

Comment: I think I'm correct in stating this is only feasible on the firmware side of things where you'd have direct control over the unicam component (which is the component that receives data from the camera and streams it into the GPU's memory); see [this section](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html#background-processes) of the camera hardware docs for a little more info.